# Java SWT Tree Expand All / Collapse All

Tags: java, tree, swt

How can I make an Expand All and a Collapse All functionality for my own SWT Tree, similar to the Collapse All button in Eclipse's Package Explorer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are just using the SWT `Tree` you must loop through all the items in the tree and expand / collapse each one. For example:

```
boolean expanded = true to expand, false to collapse

Tree tree = ... your tree

tree.setRedraw(false);  // Stop redraw until operation complete

TreeItem [] items = tree.getItems();

for (TreeItem item : items) {
   item.setExpanded(expanded);
}

tree.setRedraw(true);
```

If you are using the JFace `TreeViewer` call the viewer `collapseAll` or `expandAll` methods.

Comment: If you are using the JFace TreeViewer, be aware that [there is a bug that causes the mouse pointer to flicker](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=502841) when expanding large trees. The workaround is to call `expandAll()` from a runnable that is passed to `BusyIndicator::showWhile()`.

Comment: Why do you need to stop redrwaw until the operation is complete?

Comment: @Professor901 It stops the individual expands being drawn separately, slowing things down and possibly causing flickering.